# Pushing React client and Rails API to Heroku, I'm hitting an error with the build script

Tags: reactjs, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I recognize that there are several questions out there with a similar/same issue, but I have not been able to find a working solution from those posts yet. When running `git push heroku master`, the build runs for a while, then crashes with the following error:

```
       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_f22760141a320d80dbbda0a359da5e4b/client
       > react-scripts build

       /tmp/build_f22760141a320d80dbbda0a359da5e4b/client/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/deep-equal.js:17
           options = { prototype: true, ...options };
                                        ^^^
       SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
           at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
           at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
(it goes on for a bit more)

       npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
       npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_f22760141a320d80dbbda0a359da5e4b/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_f22760141a320d80dbbda0a359da5e4b/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" "build"
       npm ERR! node v6.3.1
       npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script 'react-scripts build'.
```

There is more to it above and below, but I believe that is the relevant portion. My suspicion from reading this and other errors is that my package.json file is not set up correctly. Here is what I hope are the helpful portions to see:

```
// root package.json:
...
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.4",
    "npm": ">= 4.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "postinstall": "npm run build && npm run deploy && echo 'Client built!'"
  },
...

// and /client/package.json:
...javascript
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

I was following [this](https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/reactjs-ruby-on-rails-api-heroku-app-2645c93f0814) article while structuring my app, and it all went well until the deploy to Heroku.

Here are some other potentially useful things to note:

```
// Profile
web: bundle exec rails s

// Heroku buildpacks:
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/ruby

// Node and npm are both updated
```

This is my first question on here, so I am sorry if there is insufficient or unnecessary information. Any help on where to look to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is working now, and all I did was:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Working on setting up Heroku. It's not working"
git push origin master
```

Then when I ran `git push heroku master`, it built! My guess is that Heroku was watching for changes to my master branch, and all the work I did reading other people's posts was never pushed to master. Very much a guess on that though.